# How to receive php array from ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to receive array from php file by ajax , I tried Encode but didn't work , Any help?

php file :

```
$Data = array()
foreach($Query as $User){
    //get Year variable
    if($Year['Year'] == $YearPosted){
        //get Name variable
        $Data['Id'] = $Name['FirstName']." ".$Name['LastName'];

    }
}
echo json_encode($Data);
```

js file :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Ajax/Users/GetUsers.php",
        data: {
            year: Year
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Id)
        }
    });
```

I want to receive from php File Something Like that

```
var User = [{
  "1": "Name of UserId One"
}, {
  "2": "Name of UserId One"
}]
```

Comment: try to add _dataType: 'json',_ to your ajax call. If you make some search on SO you can find a lot of questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like below, variable may be undefined because you did not mention field of your table.

**php side**

```
$Data = array()
foreach($Query as $key => $User){

    //get Year variable
    if($Year['Year'] == $YearPosted){
        //get Name variable
        $Data[$key]['Id'] = $Name['FirstName']." ".$Name['LastName'];

    }
}
echo json_encode($Data);
```

From js side

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Ajax/Users/GetUsers.php",
        data: {
            year: Year
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data.id);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new array level:

```
$Data = array()
foreach($Query as $User){
    //get Year variable
    if($Year['Year'] == $YearPosted){
        //get Name variable
        $Data[] = [$Data['Id'] => $Name['FirstName']." ".$Name['LastName']];
    }
}
echo json_encode($Data);
```