# How to return data from PHP to a ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I am currently learning php and I am trying to get data from php file using the below script but i am not getting any response

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "mark_mod.php",
            data: data_set,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) { 
                alert("Response : " ); // not triggering
            }
        });
```

my php return stmt

Comment: Are youn `echo`ing in your php file?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820130/6309457 OR https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404102/6309457

Comment: Welcome. You should post the `.php` script that doesn't seem to work

Comment: please post your php code or check yourself are you `echo` or `print` the response

Comment: <?php
$retJason = '[
  {
   "userid":"'.$out_userid.'",
   "username":"'.$out_username.'",
   "address":"'.$out_address.'"
   
  } 
 ]';

 echo $retJason; 
?>

Comment: That can’t be _all_ of your code, it uses variables that aren’t defined in what you have shown. This should get you Notices in the output (if you have proper PHP error reporting enabled; if you don’t – go and do that first of all now!) Are you trying to access the POST parameter that you are sending with the request here? That is not how that works in PHP, please go read up on these basics in a beginner’s tutorial in that case.

Comment: Also, have you checked what the browser console and network panel have to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Responses. I got the Solution to my problem. It seems since Ajax is asynchronous... its taking time to receive the resultant echo value from my php file. so I had to synchronize my Jquery using async : False.

Answer (score 0):

There might be problems with File URL or file access. You can use `complete` callback to check request for errors like that:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "mark_mod.php",
    data: data_set,
    dataType: "JSON",

    success: function(data) { 
        alert("Response : " );
    },

    // This method will be fired when request completes
    complete: function(xxhr, status) {
        alert("Status code: " + status);
    }

});
```

If the status code is not `success` that means there is something wrong with your request.
You can check more callback options [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

> It doesn't matter whether you use `return` or `echo` in your PHP file.
>   The `success` method must get a call if it's fine. However, if you use
>   `return` instead of `echo`, nothing will append to your request's `data`.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, The PHP response will include in your 'data' variable in the function success.

You need use data in the assync function success

```
success: function(data) { 
    alert("Response : " + data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('#formID').on('submit',function(){
const data_set={
name:"Nipu chakraborty",
"phone":"01783837xxx"
}       
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "mark_mod.php",
            data: data_set,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            }
        });
   });
});
```